# Autofilter excel not equal to

Tags: excel, basic

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "a", "b", "c", "="), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
```

I would like to select anything other than d, instead of using this array which I have to specify all in order for it to work.

Is there a symbol in excel which represent not equal to?
So I could use this code instead.
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="d"